# search a group of string in a file is present in another file or not

Tags: perl

I"m writing to perl script where basically want to open a file having many strings(one string in one line) and compare each of these strings is present in another file(search file) and print each occurrence of it. I have written the below code for one particular string finding. How can i improve it for list of strings from a file.

```
open(DATA, "<filetosearch.txt") or die "Couldn't open file filetosearch.txt for reading: $!";
my $find = "word or string to find";
#open FILE, "<signatures.txt";
my @lines = <DATA>;
print "Lined that matched $find\n";
for (@lines) {
    if ($_ =~ /$find/) {
        print "$_\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the strings from either file fit in memory all at once?

Comment: You're opening filetosearch.txt for writing, not reading.

Comment: Yes, the files are around 500 lines and fit in memory. Ok i shall correct the filetosearch.txt to read only as:open(DATA, "<filetosearch.txt") or die "Couldn't open file filetosearch.txt for reading: $!";

Comment: `grep -F -f signatures.txt filetosearch.txt`

Comment: `grep -C3 -F -x -f file1 file2`

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;

tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', 'filetosearch.txt';
my @matched;
my @result;
tie my @patterns, 'Tie::File', 'patterns.txt';
foreach my $pattern (@patterns)
{
    $pattern = quotemeta $pattern;
    @matched = grep { /$pattern/ } @lines;
    push @result, @matched;
}
```

- I use Tie::File, because it is convenient (not especially in this case, but others), others (perhaps a lot of others?) would disagree, but it is of no importance here
- grep is a core function, that is very good at what it does (In my experience)

Comment: +1 for suggesting using `Tie::File` for this case.  It can be *notoriously slow* with large files, but the OP's not dealing with such.  Consider `/\Q$pattern\E/` as there may be meta-characters in the strings.

Comment: @Kenosis Thank you Kenosis, I inserted your suggestion. Personally I prefer to use quotemeta, as I think it improves readability.

Comment: You're most welcome!  Your readability point makes sense.  You could certainly `$pattern = quotemeta $pattern;` before `grep`ping.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, something like this will be faster.

```
sub testmatch
{
  my ($find, $linesref)= @_ ;

  for ( @$linesref ) { if ( $_ =~ /$find/ ) { return 1 ; } }
  return 0 ;
}

{
  open(DATA, "<filetosearch.txt") or die "die" ;
  my @lines = <DATA> ;

  open(SRC, "tests.txt") ;
  while (<SRC>)
  {
    if ( testmatch( $_, \@lines )) { print "a match\n" }
  }
}
```

If its matching full line to full line, you can pack the one line in as keys to a hash and just test existance:

```
{
  open(DATA, "<filetosearch.txt") or die "die" ;
  my %lines ;
  @lines{<DATA>}= undef ;

  open(SRC, "tests.txt") ;
  while (<SRC>)
  {
     if ($_ ~~ %lines) { print "a match\n" }
  }
}
```

Comment: Always and without fail `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: actually I just use 5.012 ;

Comment: Thanks very much Woolstar. But i forgot to include that i wanted to print the 3 lines before, from the match pattern. How do i do that?

Comment: @woolstar: that enables strict, but not warnings.

Comment: @woolstar: It is very bad practice to use `use <version>` to mean anything other than *“this code uses features unavailable before Perl <version>”*. You are expecting people to carry around in their heads a catalogue of the additional features that every such `use` implies (`use 5.10` *doesn't* include `use strict`) and it is reasonable for someone to remove that statement if it is clear that there is nothing in the code that depends on the stated version.

Comment: I pretty much depend on at least 5.012 feature set (quick match, and given evaluating to a value).  That to me is baseline modern perl.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $searchFile = pop;
my @strings    = map { chomp; "\Q$_\E" } <>;
my $regex      = '(?:' . ( join '|', @strings ) . ')';

push @ARGV, $searchFile;

while (<>) {
    print if /$regex/;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl strings.txt searchFile.txt [>outFile.txt]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

First, the search file's name is (implicitly) `pop`ped off `@ARGV` and saved for later.  Then the strings' file is read (`<>`) and `map` is used to `chomp` each line, escape meta-characters (the `\Q` and `\E`, in case there may be regex chars, e.g., a '.' or '*' etc., in the string) then these lines are passed to an array.  The array's elements are `join`ed with the regex alternation character (`|`) to effectively form an `OR` statement of all the strings that will be matched against each of the search file's lines.  Next, the search file's name is `push`ed onto `@ARGV` so its lines can be searched. Again, each line is `chomp`ed and `print`ed if one of the strings are found on the line.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this will do the job:

```
open FILE1, "filetosearch.txt";
my @arrFileToSearch = <FILE1>;
close FILE1;

open FILE2, "signatures.txt";
my @arrSignatures = <FILE2>;
close FILE2;

for(my $i = 0; defined($arrFileToSearch[$i]);$i++){
    foreach my $signature(@arrSignatures){
        chomp($signature);
        $signature = quotemeta($signature);#to be sure you are escaping special characters
        if($arrFileToSearch[$i] =~ /$signature/){
            print $arrFileToSearch[$i-3];#or any other index that you want
        }
    }
```

}